Analyze the convexity of $xe^{y}$
Consider
$$f(x,y)=xe^y$$
where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. To prove the convexity of $f(x,y)$ we need to form the Hessian and check if it is positive semidefinite. So consider the following partial derivatives
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
f_x(x,y) = e^y
&
f_y(x,y) = xe^y
&
\\
f_{xx}(x,y) = 0
&
f_{yy}(x,y) = xe^y
\\
f_{xy}(x,y) = e^y
&
f_{yx}(x,y) = e^y
\end{array}
$$
so we can form the Hessian as
$$
H(x,y) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
f_{xx}(x,y) & f_{xy}(x,y) \\
f_{yx}(x,y) & f_{yy}(x,y)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & e^y \\
e^y & xe^y
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, in the conditions for convexity and concavity. For convexity we need $H(x,y)\ge0$, which requires both of the following to be satisfied

$H(x,y)[1,1]\ge0$
$\det H(x,y)\ge0$

For concavity we need $H(x,y)\le0$, which requires both of the following to be satisfied

$H(x,y)[1,1]\le0$
$\det H(x,y)\le0$

Now let's check the definiteness of $\det H(x,y)$
$$
\det H(x,y) = 0\left(xe^y\right) - (e^y)(e^y) = -e^{2y}
$$
From this we can see that $\det H(x,y)<0$, meaning that $f(x,y)$ is concave.

As an additional check of the above proof, we will consider the convexity property that if $f(x,y)$ is concave then $-f(x,y)$ is convex. So let's now try to prove that $g(x,y)=-xe^y$ is convex.
Consider the following partial derivatives
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
g_x(x,y) = -e^y
&
g_y(x,y) = -xe^y
&
\\
g_{xx}(x,y) = 0
&
g_{yy}(x,y) = -xe^y
\\
g_{xy}(x,y) = -e^y
&
g_{yx}(x,y) = -e^y
\end{array}
$$
so we can form the Hessian as
$$
G(x,y) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -e^y \\
-e^y & -xe^y
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now let's check the definiteness of $\det G(x,y)$
$$
\det G(x,y) = 0\left(-xe^y\right) - (-e^y)(-e^y) = -e^{2y}
$$
From this we can see that $\det G(x,y)<0$, meaning that $g(x,y)$ is concave.

So how can $f(x,y)$ and $-f(x,y)$ be concave?
According to Boyd p. 71, "$f$ is concave if and only if $\text{dom} f$ is convex and its Hessian is negative semidefinite." This is a necessary and sufficient condition, so what's going on with my example function?"

Because $\det G(x,y)<0$ implies the function is neither concave nor convex.

Why does it imply neither concave nor convex?

Because the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues.
